# Writing to TIFF: illegal byte order

Tags: java, image, tiff, endianness

I have been trying to draw a huge image file from lots of smaller Images in BufferedImage-format (using one big BufferedImage takes more memory than I have) and am now trying to do this via the replacePixels-Function of the ImageWriter-class.

However; i do get a puzzling error which even extensive Googleing could not fix, so I hope someone here can tell me what I'm doing wrong:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Illegal byte order
at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageWriter.locateIFD(TIFFImageWriter.java:2813)
at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageWriter.readIFD(TIFFImageWriter.java:3076)
at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageWriter.canReplacePixels(TIFFImageWriter.java:3099)
at drawingTiles.WorldMapMaker$1.writeImg(WorldMapMaker.java:90)
at drawingTiles.WorldMapMaker$1.run(WorldMapMaker.java:148)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
javax.imageio.IIOException: Illegal byte order
at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageWriter.locateIFD(TIFFImageWriter.java:2813)
at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageWriter.readIFD(TIFFImageWriter.java:3076)
at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageWriter.prepareReplacePixels(TIFFImageWriter.java:3141)
at drawingTiles.WorldMapMaker$1.writeImg(WorldMapMaker.java:104)
at drawingTiles.WorldMapMaker$1.run(WorldMapMaker.java:148)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I do know what a byte order is, I do not know how a byte-order can be illegal. This is the function I am using:

```
public void writeImg (String path, int startx, int starty, BufferedImage image){
            File output = new File(path);
            ImageOutputStream ios = null;
            try {
                ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(output);
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Iterator<ImageWriter> iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("TIF");
            ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter)iter.next();
            writer.setOutput(ios);

            TIFFImageWriteParam writeParam = new TIFFImageWriteParam(Locale.ENGLISH);
            writeParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);

            try{
                if(writer.canReplacePixels(0)){ // LINE 90
                    System.out.println("True");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("False");
                }
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Point destinationOffset = new Point(startx,starty);
            writeParam.setDestinationOffset(destinationOffset);

            try {
                writer.prepareReplacePixels(0, new Rectangle(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight())); // LINE 104
                writer.replacePixels(image, writeParam);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look here, you can see the source to [TiffImageWriter](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/6.0-JDK-Modules/Java-Advanced-Imaging/com/sun/media/imageioimpl/plugins/tiff/TIFFImageWriter.java.htm).

And I see this code in `locateIfd()`:

```
  long startPos = stream.getStreamPosition();

  stream.seek(headerPosition);
  int byteOrder = stream.readUnsignedShort();
  if (byteOrder == 0x4d4d) {
      stream.setByteOrder(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
  } else if (byteOrder == 0x4949) {
      stream.setByteOrder(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
  } else {
      stream.seek(startPos);
      throw new IIOException("Illegal byte order");
  }
```

When setOutput() is called on this stream, a member is set called headerPosition, which is the stream's current position at that point.  This code seeks back to that point and looks for either Intel or Motorola byte orders and throws if it finds anything else.  I'm guessing that your stream is in the wrong place when locateIfd gets called.

As an aside, how big are the images?  I ask because I work for a company that has [an image processing library](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/joltimage) for Java and our image model has the ability to have images built from more complex memory models than contiguous and I could imagine making a composite memory model made from a list of images that exist elsewhere which virtualizes them.  I think we're currently forced to use the built-in Tiff codec and we'd be in the same boat as you wrt to memory, but if you could live with Png, this would work.